# Detect a missing PWM signal in the smallest possible board space

Tags: pwm, watchdog

I have a motor control board that basically has zero space left, and the customer wants to add a fault flag to tell if their 2 kHz PWM input signal is lost.

So basically, I need to detect a lack of edges over a few milliseconds, using a small number of very small components. There is no microcontroller on the board, and I have maybe 10 square millimeters I can scrape together for it.

I had the idea to use a watchdog supervisor IC, but I can't find a small one that is active high and has the right timeout period. Now I'm leaning towards something with a 555 timer or maybe an RC filter that fills from 5v and gets drained whenever there's an edge.

Comment: There are microcontrollers that fit in 10mm^2, I believe in DFN packages and smaller.  With the correct microcontroller this task becomes trivial, just setup an interrupt that is edge triggered and increments a variable, count for a certain amount of time, and see if the number of counts matches what you think it should.

Comment: @krb686 the programming pins and other required minimum circuitry may not fit the bill. 10mm^2 is a tiny area, barely more than 3x3mm. a few 0603 size capacitors and their footprints immediately breach this ;(

Comment: @KyranF Well that's assuming he needs to be able to reprogram the microcontroller while on the board.  Otherwise, he could just as easily use an off board programmer and then populate with pre-programmed chips.  In fact, one microcontroller that I know for sure can fit this bill is the ATtiny4/5/9/10 series, that comes in a 2mmx2mm uDFN package.

Comment: @krb686 and how hard is it to program one of these out-of-circuit without special jigs and equipment? Specifically DFN package, DIP chip packages are easy to put in carrier mounts for programming.

Comment: @KyranF I'm sure you would essentially *have* to use a special jig or piece of equipment such as a specially made socket.  2mm x 2mm is a very, very small space.  Also, what about DIP? DIP is far too large to meet the OP's space requirement.

Comment: @KryanF Rather difficult to find as it seems not many make such adapters, however something like this could be used. http://goo.gl/4jeRgx

Comment: @krb686 actually this is a cool reason to use "Z axis tape" for on that breakout board for example. [Check out the Z axis tape](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12042) You put the tape down, then put the IC on the pads, and the tape conducts upwards to the pins but not sideways - you can program the MCUs and then take them off the tape.. watch the product video haha

Comment: @KyranF wow that tape is kind of insane

Comment: What would the fault output signal have to look like? May a simple RC lowpass filter be sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This circuit should do what you want, within your space requirments.

At 2 kHz, pulses will arrive at 500 µS intervals.  I set the timing for the 74123 multivibrator to timeout at 2 ms.

You wanted an active high output when the pulses disappeared, by unfortunately, in small packages like this, there is no \$\mathsf{\small \overline{\text{Q}}} \$ output, so I had to include an inverter.  Otherwise that would have come for free.

[image]

Both the 74123 and 7404 are in BGA type packages. The [SN74LVC1G123](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g123.pdf), in a YZIP package is 0.9mm x 1.9 mm, or 1.71 mm².  The [SN74LVC1G04](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g04.pdf), in a X2SON package, is 0.8 x 0.8 mm, 0.64 mm².  Since they are BGA, they can be placed as close together as the pick and place machine will allow.

The two caps and resistor all come in 0201 packages, which are each 0.6 mm x 0.3 mm, say 0.9 mm x .35 mm footprint on the PCB.   So the total for all three is 0.945 mm².  Thus the total area for all five components (excluding room for traces) is approximately 3.3 mm².

Comment: I really like this idea. I actually managed to clear up some more space on the board so I can use the tiny-but-not-BGA versions of these ICs. I ran into one problem going through the datasheet though. It looks like they have Cext connected to ground in the datasheet. Is this datasheet just out of whack? http://i.imgur.com/ULvayLZ.png

Comment: Also, how do I calculate a different timeout value? This is like the worst datasheet ever. @tcrosley

Comment: @Chriszuma I noticed that too on one datasheet.  It doesn't make any sense at all -- why not just ground the capacitor ant not waste the pin?  If you type 74123 into Google, and look at the various images, I think you'll find them all match mine.

Comment: @Chriszuma Timeout value in ms is 0.37 * R(in kΩ) * C (in µF), so my T = .37 * 60.4 * .1 = 2.2 ms.  I got the formula from [here](http://www2.elo.utfsm.cl/~lsb/elo211/datos/lacaja/74123.pdf).  p.s. if you can find a 74x123 small enough with a "not Q" output, you won't need the inverter.

Comment: @Chriszuma I just checked oen of our products where I am using a 74123, and the Cext pin is definitely not grounded.

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful. How did you know which one of the part numbers in that app note matches the TI part though?

Comment: @Chriszuma Since they didn't have an LVC family part, I just picked an LS part.  The constants don't differ too much, 0.29, 0.34 and 0.37, so as long as you don't try to make the timing too tight, you should be okay.  You might want to calculate times with both the 0.29 and 0.37 multipliers.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a peak detector and a comparator.  Run the PWM input through a diode to a parallel capacitor and resistor to ground.  The output of this should follow the highest level of the input signal and will decay to GND with the RC time constant of the resistor and capacitor.  However, this will only detect a stuck low signal.

If you want to detect both, you could probably get away with two peak detectors, one looking for the high level (tie parallel RC to ground) and one looking for the low level (tie parallel RC to power).  Then use a dual comparator to generate the error signal if the high level is too low or the low level is too high (you get a free wired AND gate with an open-drain dual comparator).

Comment: In your second paragraph, you stated "If you need to detect both..."  However the OP already said "I need to detect a *lack* of edges over a few milliseconds".  So you need only one comparator.

Comment: Lack of edges could be caused by a signal that is stuck high or stuck low.  If you use a peak detector, you can't assume that a high level out of a peak detector means the signal is toggling, it just means that it has been high for some time, which could be much longer than you would like.

Answer (score 1):

A sot232 sized Pic10f with some basic coding would fit. Closest thing to fit the limited size requirements without going leadless/bga/wlp. All it would be doing is listening for the pwm signal on one gpio and toggling another gpio if lost.

Comment: I am unaware of any other smaller and/or leadless 6 or 4 pin general purpose microcontroller.

Comment: Why would the OP want to avoid BGA?  I am sure if the board is already as crammed as he says it is, then they are probably already using lots of leadless packages.

Comment: Or maybe it's precisely because they aren't using leadless packages that the board is so packed.

Comment: @tcrosley specialized equipment needed depending on what OPs board process already is. I made an assumption that this would be an add on to an existing premade board, not something that can be added in for initial board run. And a leadless package might require more than 2 layers, complicated runs, programming tools. A sot323 6 pin pic10f would be very simple imho.

Comment: @Passerby I made exactly the opposite assumptions, this was an existing board with very little space left over (as the OP says), and is probably already a 6 or 8 layer board (we use those routinely at the company I work for, as yes, we use BGA devices when we have to).

Comment: @tcrosley, I actually do like avoiding BGA because it makes debugging with an oscilloscope much simpler.

Comment: @Chriszuma I agree, but sometimes there are chips like processors or cell modems that have hundreds of pins and you don't have any choice. Yes, debugging is a major pain, unles you bring out lots of test points. I picked the BGA varieties because of your severe space constraints, and was trying to avoid external pins.

Comment: @tcrosley well, do you know of any 2x3 or 3x3 bga microcontrollers?

Comment: @Passerby Not sure what your point is, but the ATtiny20 comes in either a 12 ball, 1.5x1.4 mm BGA package, or a 15 ball, 3x3 mm BGA package. See pages 208 and 211 of [this datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8235-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-attiny20_datasheet.pdf).

Comment: @tcrosley my point is that small 6 or 9 pin bga are more convenient to layout and troubleshoot than bigger ones. Less test points if any needed.

Comment: @Passerby Yes agree.I hate the big ones that have four or five concentric squares of balls.